# How to write preformatted text in a form?

Tags: html, forms, tags, pre

The goal is to be able to use tabulations and other special characters.

I thought I could use `<pre>` tag and put a form inside it but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may achieve the same goal by using [html entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

For example

```html
<pre>
  (\/)
 (^.^)
(")(")
</pre>
```

Equals this:

```
&nbsp&nbsp(\/)<br>&nbsp(^.^)<br>(")(")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? I'm not sure I understood either

Comment: Oh I think I understood what you meant. It would have been good if it had been for p tag or some other tags. But what I need is for form tag: when writting something and hitting tab on keyboard, I need to have a tabulation, not moving to next element on the page.